# Ubuntu 14.04 64bit locks up after login

Tags: nvidia-optimus, 14.04, dell-vostro

Today I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit. The installation went well with no sign of issues.

On boot everything seems fine until I get to the login screen. After putting in my password and logging in the login screen disappears, however unity never loads and the mouse and keyboard become non-responsive. The only thing on the screen is the background image for the desktop. The only thing I can do at that point is force power down.

Some other possibly relevant info:

- Computer is a Dell Vostro 3300 with Nvidia Optimus (this laptop model
  came with 2 versions of optimus, mine is the 2nd version that    can
  actively switch between discrete/onboard and does not require a
  reboot to do so)
- Unfortunately Dell did not supply a way to disable Optimus in BIOS on this model.
- Tried fresh installs from 2 different flash drives and 2 live    CDs.
- No problems with previous installs of 12.04,12.10,13.04 and
    13.10.
- Reinstalled 13.10 and then upgraded to 14.04 with same results.
- Can interact with items on login screen with no issues.

Not sure what to try next?

Comment: Press `Alt+ctrl+f1`, login. Run `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`. Reboot using `sudo reboot`. Let us know if this fixed the issue. **Source**: 2 days of banging head with my laptop :(, After removing bumblebee I was in same state.

Comment: No luck. When at the login screen Alt+ctrl+f1 cause the system to lock up. I boot with failsafe graphics and was then able to purge nvidia, however there were no nvidia packages to remove. 

I am able to login to the guest account as well as my account when in failsafe graphics mode.

Comment: I too was having the same problem I tried both 32 and 64 bit but same problem then i downloaded kubuntu 14.04 it works perfect. then run the following command : $ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop && sudo apt-get remove kubuntu-desktop u will get full working unity ubuntu back....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved.

To remedy my problem I did the following:

1. Boot into failsafe graphics mode and login with normal user (or boot to terminal instead)
2. purge nvidia and bumblebee if installed `sudo apt-get purge nvidia* bumblebee*`
3. install nvidia prime `sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime`
4. Reboot

This resolved my issues after a reboot. I was able to login with no issues and verify that both graphics cards are usable and that Nvidia proprietary driver version 331.38 is in use.

Comment: so many places I see the instruction "boot into failsafe" but nowhere can I find any instructions on HOW to boot into failsafe in 14.04 -- how is this done and why does everyone assume it's common knowledge?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem resolved by your procedure, however, the X desktop just keep freezing every few minutes. I have found a workaround for the problem that may help you as well.

I installed the latest Nvidia 340 drivers from the PPA but problem remains. <kbd>CtrlAlt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> is unlocking the situation.

(System looks stable while running on battery, I presume it is linked the nvidia stepping. Also notice that freeze mostly occurs on widows opening.)

Answer (score 0):

My system would boot to loging screen, and freeze. I ended up installing the nvidia-current package, but then my resolution wouldn't go above 1024x768.  My monitor is 1920x1080, so I had to come up with yet more.

I have learned over time that my monitor (**Vizio VM230XVT**) is not detected properly on install.  If I hot-plug it as a second monitor, it works fine.  This means it can be done.  I have been using Linux exclusively for 8 years, so I have learned that all I need to do is specify my monitor h-sync and v-sync settings in the **/etc/X11/xorg.conf**  file, but the new **xrandr** steup got rid of that file!!  Now what??

They have move AND renamed the file.  Then, on top of that, the file didn't even exist.  You must create it, and place it here:
**/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf**

So what did I put in my **10-monitor.conf** file to get my resolutions??  How did I know what sync values to put in?  I read the manual, or some spec sheet.

Here is the **10-monitor.conf** file for my monitor, the **Vizio VM230XVT**.

```
Section "Monitor"
 Identifier "Monitor0"
 VendorName "Vizio"
 ModelName "VM230XVT"
 HorizSync 31.0 - 81.0
 VertRefresh 31.5 - 80.0
EndSection

Section "Screen"
  Identifier "Screen0"
  Device "VGA-0"
  Monitor "Monitor0"
  DefaultDepth 24
  SubSection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Modes "1920x1080_60.00" "1024x768" "1152x864" "800x600" "680x384" "640x480"
  EndSubSection
EndSection
```