# Unity or Gnome for Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: unity, gnome, ati, 14.04, login

I made  clean installation of Ubuntu 14.04 on 18th of April. Then to overcome the problem of heating, I installed the fglrx-updates driver for my Radeon HD 7730M graphics.
Yesterday, on boot everything looked fine until I get to the login screen. After putting in my password and logging in the login screen disappears, however my desktop never loaded and the mouse and keyboard become non-responsive. The desktop background also didn't show up. The only thing I can do at that point is force power down.

So, as per the answer given on [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449604/ubuntu-14-04-64bit-locks-up-after-login), I tried the steps but all in vain. So, I made a live USB of Ubuntu 14.04 and reinstalled in the same partitions as before. Now, It's working fine.

But can somebody tell me whether switching to GNOME is better? Because, yesterday I couldn't give a seminar since my slides were stored in Ubuntu. Now if this problem keeps popping up, it's gonna create problems for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graphics integration is still dodgy. If the GPU drivers are not working in `Unity`, they probably won't in `GNOME` either.

You can try the following if unity fails to load:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to go to `tty` shell.
2. Login and execute (for Unity)

   `$ sudo service lightdm restart`

If this works, then you might get away with your current graphics drivers.

Comment: OK. Will try when I again get this problem. But I don't think it is a problem with the GPU driver. Because I installed it at least 1 week ago. And there was no problem. Not even the one saying "Your system is running in low graphics mode".

Comment: For now, my system is working better without any graphics drivers. Still using 14.04. I think the problem was just with Unity. Now GNOME is working fine.